# App looks different on simulator and view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

When i run the app on simulator it looks different from the view controller storyboard. I guess it is a problem with auto layout , but i don't know how to fix it. What should i do? Thank you in advance.

edit: It looks perfect in simulator iphone 5 or 5s , but it looks different if i change the simulator to iphone 4s , 6 or 6plus.

[image]

Comment: Here the screenshots: http://imgur.com/jntnXYI,0jKIK4w,2GxWZbW,LDT5SVN

Comment: You really need to give us more details / screenshots as currently there is no problem visible (to me).

Comment: The problem is that the red button is  on the center if i run the app on iphone5/5s simulator but it is not if i run it on iphone4s/6/6plus simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center the button in superview, select the red button, firstly go to Editor --> Align --> Horizontal center in container. Secondly go to Editor --> Pin --> Leading space to superview/Top space to super view to add top space and leading space to super view, or you can just click adding missing constraints in storyboard, which adds missing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used auto layouts then make sure that margins option is not selected, as it adjusts margins and it affects the position of the control.

Comment: Where do i check if it is selected or not?

Comment: when you add a new constraint for left,right,top,bottom spaces it has margin option checked, uncheck that option